# How to deploy large python packages with AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I need some advice.

I trained an image classifier using Tensorflow and wanted to deploy it to AWS Lambda using [serverless](https://serverless.com/). The directory includes the model, some python modules including tensorflow and numpy, and python code. The size of the complete folder before unzipping is 340 MB, which gets rejected by AWS lambda with an error message saying `"The unzipped state must be smaller than 262144000 bytes"`.

How should I approach this? Can I not deploy packages like these on AWS Lambda?

Note: In the requirements.txt file, there are 2 modules listed including numpy and tensorflow. (Tensorflow is a big module)

Comment: 340 MB seems large for a trained classifier....

Comment: @MitchWheat python modules numpy and tensorflow both contribute around 333 MB

Comment: @MitchWheat Is there a way I could use modules without uploading?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am answering it very late .. just putting it here for reference for other people..
I did the following things -

1. Delete /external/* /tensorflow/contrib/* /tensorflow/include/unsupported/* files as suggested [here](https://medium.com/bbc-design-engineering/evaluating-tensorflow-models-in-aws-lambda-c0e06cf23d87).
2. Strip all .so files especially two files in site-packages/numpy/core - _multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and _multiarray_tests.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so. Strip considerably reduces their size.
3. You can put your model in S3 bucket and download it at runtime. This will reduce the size of the zip. This is explained in detail [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-deep-learning-models-with-aws-lambda-and-tensorflow/).

If this does not work then there are some additional things that can be done like removing pyc files etc as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Accenture/serverless-ephemeral/blob/master/docs/build-tensorflow-package.md)

Comment: What size were you able to reduce this to?

Comment: The original size was around 380MB and I was able to reduce it to 234MB. I was using tensorflow 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use the ephemeral disk capacity, (/tmp) that have a limit of 512Mb, but in your case, memory will still be an issue.

The best choice can be to use an AWS batch, if serverless does not manage it, you can even keep a lambda to trigger your batch

Comment: I cannot understand this. How do people manage with tensorflow? If you see this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-deep-learning-models-with-aws-lambda-and-tensorflow/ , they are using tensorflow in code but do not tell how did they upload it using lambda

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to use the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/) as outlined in [this article](https://read.iopipe.com/the-right-way-to-do-serverless-in-python-e99535574454). It helps to zip them using a docker image which mimics Amazon's linux environment. Additionally, it automatically uses S3 as the code repository for your Lambda which increases the size limit. The article provided is an extremely helpful guide and is the same way that developers use tensorflow and other large libraries on AWS.

If you're still running into the 250MB size limit, you can try to follow [this article](https://tech.europace.de/slimifying-aws-lambdas/) which uses the same `python-requirements-plugin` as the previous article, but with the option `-slim: true`. This will help you to optimally compress your packages by removing unnecessary files from them, which allows you to decrease your package size before AND after unzipping.