# Deploying a microservice with Tensorflow at AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda

I have been stuck here for too long. I am trying to deploy a microservice that uses tensorflow. There is a single file by the name of `handler.py` which has the simple code below:

```
import json
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def main(event, context):
    # a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)

    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event
    }

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response

    # Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY
    # integration
    """
    return {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "event": event
    }
    """
```

To make my work easier I am using [serverless to deploy a microservice](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) but it fails saying, unzipped size is too big. Here is how my directory looks like:

```
-- handler.py
-- serverless.yml
-- requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt` looks like:

```
numpy
tensorflow
```

I also tried to upload without installing the above modules thinking that lambda will itself initialize from `requirements.txt` but then get an error that `Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'tensorflow'`. What should I do? I have spent lots of time in this and still not convinced that AWS Lambda would not allow me to do this.

If you wanted to see `serverless.yml`, it looks as follows:

```
service: numpy-new-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  profile: nsp
  role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx7:role/AdminRole

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: test
          method: get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned from the error you received it looks like your zipped package is too large. You received that other error because you have a module requirement in your script to use tensorflow.

Keep in mind the [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#w135aac55b9c19) has a 50MB deployment package size limit. The [Tensorflow package](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) by itself is close to 50MB, so adding the Numpy package will take it well over the limit.

Have a look at this blog which does some investigation into the package limit sizing in AWS Lambda

https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-aws-lambda-deployment-limits-9a8384b0bec3

Comment: Do you mean I need to zip the folder that has python modules and then again zip the complete package? Does that also mean, I should be reading the modules from the local-python folder?

Comment: Nope you only need to zip it once and yes you should be reading the python libraries from the local python folder. In Lambda you need to prepackage the library files in your deployment with your code.

Comment: Do you need to use numpy in your code? Maybe keeping numpy out of the deployment might just keep it under this limit. In this example https://github.com/jacopotagliabue/tensorflow_to_lambda_serverless it looks like they can deploy successfully with just the Tensorflow library.

Comment: Need numpy too. Total unzipped size of the package is 330 MB

Comment: AWS Lambda probably isn't the best tool to use then if you have such a large package to run your service. I've added a blog entry that I just had a read of which might be interesting for this case.

Comment: Tensorflow and numpy together make up 322 MB. Tenorflow is huge

Comment: From the document you shared, it appears that it is not possible to deploy a package with size 330 MB

Comment: There are multiple ways to reduce the size of tensorflow+numpy deployment package. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503912/how-to-deploy-large-python-packages-with-aws-lambda/55626484#55626484)