# Alternative to AWS lambda when deployment package is greater than 250MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I want to launch some code serverless, I use AWS Lambda. However, this time my deployment package is greater than 250MB.

So I can't deploy it on a Lambda...

I want to know what are the alternatives in this case?

Comment: Have you identified what's consuming so much space?

Comment: Yes. It's my python dependencies (gensim and pandas use a lot of space).

Comment: You should create layers for your dependencies and make your lambda depend on them

Comment: How do you implement that?

Comment: @yorodm Whether or not you use Layers, the total unzipped size of the function and all layers can't exceed the unzipped deployment package size limit of 250 MB. Simply moving packages to a layer doesn't help. You need to optimize for size, and then optionally deploy via Layers.

Comment: @jarmod Ok in my case I could optimize my packet size. But imagine it is not possible, another AWS service could do the job?

Comment: Yes, you might look at AWS Batch. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503912/how-to-deploy-large-python-packages-with-aws-lambda in case it leads to something that helps. I'm assuming that these very large Python packages are not natively optimized for size so there may be ways to rebuild them with that goal in mind.

Comment: When I deployed some large python libraries to lambda e.g. Numpy, Matplotlib, etc I just ended up manually stripping out files my lambda doesn't need from the packages files in `site_packages` before making the deployment package. I got my lambda down from 450mb to just 40mb, no joke. Your function probably doesn't need everything in those kinds of libraries.

Comment: Dependency management would help you. Have a look here for a detailed explanation: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-shrink-numpy-scipy-pandas-and-matplotlib-for-your-data-product-4ec8d7e86ee4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd question your architecture. If you are running into problems with how AWS has designed a service (i.e. lambda 250mb max size) its likely you are using the service in a way it wasn't intended.

An anti-pattern I often see is people stuffing all their code into one function. Similar to how you'd deploy all your code to a single server. This is not really the use case for AWS lambda.

Does your function do one thing? If not, refactor it out into different functions doing different things. This may help remove dependencies when you split into multiple functions.

Another thing you can look at is can you code the function in a different language (another reason to keep functions small). I once had a lambda function in python that went over 250mb. When I looked at solving the same problem with node.js, my function size dropped to 20mb.

Comment: Yes I know the use case of the lambda function and I have already split my main function into several lambda functions. To solve the problem, I use the serverless framework :)

Comment: Interesting - I'm not sure how the serverless framework has reduced your lambda  size without you reducing your codebase. Happy you have the problem solved though :-)

Comment: I use the method described here: https://read.iopipe.com/the-right-way-to-do-serverless-in-python-e99535574454. A plugin "dockerize" pip dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is before run the lambda function you can download the dependencies to /tmp folder from s3 bucket and then add it to python path, it would give you extra 512MB, although you need to take into consideration the download time for some of the lambda invocations